# Does tail -f always use inotify?

Tags: linux, tail

I am using tail -f (on Linux) and am trying to figure out how I should use the -s parameter to set the polling interval. A colleague told me that -s0 would cause tail to use inotify instead of polling but I cannot find that in the documentation for tail.

The binary files I am tailing change constantly - does this suggest I should use -s0 or some fraction of second (like -s0.1) instead?

Comment: Always? Not *always* -- not all kernels are guaranteed to support inotify.

Comment: `man tail`: "with -f, sleep for approximately N seconds (default 1.0) between iterations;  with  inotify and --pid=P, check process P at least        once every N seconds"

Comment: That said -- if your `tail` *does* support `inotify`, then you don't really need `-s`. I would strongly advise leaving it to defaults; the program's author/maintainer are in a better position to know what reasonable values are than anyone else, after all.

Comment: `strace` it and see for yourself.

Comment: @PSkocik, even that provides only information on current behavior, not on documented semantics -- meaning that any information gleaned that way is prone to change without notice in future releases.

Comment: By the way -- I rarely see an appropriate use case for using `tail` with a binary file -- being, as it is, a line-oriented tool. Are you sure you shouldn't be writing your own inotify client?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy we use tail with binary files a lot to feed command line parsing apps from stdin. It seems to work fine in general but I am trying to find the most optimal parameters for our use.

Comment: @MarcB yes I looked at the man page before posting. it mentions inotify but does not make the relationship between inotify and command line parameters clear.

Comment: If you want better control, you can prevent the use of inotify with the `---disable-inotify` option (note the three dashes).

Comment: @MarkPlotnick where did you find documentation for that option? It is not mentioned on the man page for tail on my (Centos 5) linux.

Comment: That struck me as very intentionally undocumented, when I ran across it in the source.

Comment: @PSkocik I used strace on tail -f, tail -s0.1 -f and tail -s0 -f. All of them poll using fstat() with different delays. The first (default) polls once a second, the second looks like it polled faster (tenth of a second), the last looked like it calls fstat() in as fast a loop as possible - which seems like a crazy thing to do from a performance point of view. No mention of "inotify" anywhere.

Comment: @KevinOlree I'm getting inotify regardless of what I put in the `-s0.1` or if I use it at all. Also on Linux.

Comment: @KevinOlree It's not in the man page or info doc. I read about it on [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/882147) when I was looking into [this U&L question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147640/not-able-to-see-the-progression-of-a-file-with-tail-f).

Comment: CentOS 5?! I wouldn't tend to expect modern features there. (inotify exists, but that doesn't mean your tail will support it).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yeah - sadly RH/Centos 5 is where I am stuck for this project for historical reasons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, `tail -f` does not always use `inotify`.

`inotify` is not always available. Even if your kernel supports it, only a limited number of handles are available for watching files with inotify, and they may be in use somewhere else. Moreover, if any file in the list of names passed to `tail` is not on a local filesystem, polling will be used unconditionally.

The smart thing to do here is to trust the maintainers to have configured default behavior to be appropriately tuned for a reasonable balance of efficiency and performance, and avoid second-guessing. This is doubly so since (lacking clearly documented semantics around behavior with `-s 0`) any advice we gave here could become out-of-date in future releases.

---

Regardless: If your system does in fact support inotify, you'll be seeing lower latency than the default one-second polling period would suggest already, out-of-the-box, with no tuning or non-default options needed.

See [the actual delay loop used for `tail -f` with inotify available](https://github.com/goj/coreutils/blob/rm-d/src/tail.c#L1469); you'll see that the time passed with `-s` is given as a timeout to the select() call, but that this timeout is only reached if inotify does not return any events prior to that point.

Comment: so I should assume that if my kernel supports inotify and there are inotify handles available then my tail -f will use inotify even if I set the -s command line parameter?

Comment: and that setting `-s` will make tail waste resources by polling to check for events inotify didn't provide notice of, yes. See https://github.com/goj/coreutils/blob/rm-d/src/tail.c#L1469 -- `sleep_interval` is still used, but as an argument to a select() call that has FDs to wait on as well, so it'll only break out if no other changes come in in the time given.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, apart of everything you say, that's ok... I have to add that using a `0.1s` delay for polling allows a person to expect almost continous flow of information, and without apparent overloading the cpu.

Comment: @LuisColorado, sure -- but this question was about inotify use, and when inotify is available and supported by the local copy of `tail -f` (and other prerequisites are met, ie. local filesystem), you don't need to use `-s 0.1` to get that fluid stream.

Comment: Yes, but my point was for a workaround about it, just when `inotify` is not available.  The most probable thing is that it will be, either (as ubuntu with a standard kernel has it activated) so there's no place to discussion.  I said before pointing anything that your answers had nothing to question.